# Search for datetime value in each item of a list of filenames

Tags: python, datetime, search, boto3

I have a lot of csv files in a folder in an S3 bucket, I've written some code that creates a list of all the file names in the folder.

A sample of the list looks like this:

```
 file_list = ['live/live_raw/july18/xxxx_yyyyyyyyy_zzzzzzz_20180730_MET40.txt',
 'live/live_raw/july18/xxxx_yyyyyyyyy_zzzzzzz__20180730_MET41.txt',
 'live/live_raw/july18/xxxx_yyyyyyyyy_zzzzzzz__20180731_MET42.txt',
 'live/live_raw/july18/xxxx_yyyyyyyyy_zzzzzzz__20180731_MET43.txt',
 'live/live_raw/july18/xxxx_yyyyyyyyy_zzzzzzz__20170731_MET44.txt']
```

I want to make new sub-lists for the unique dates, something like this:

```
matching_("%Y%m%d") = [s for s in file_list if strftime("%Y%m%d") in s]
```

Resulting in:

```
matching_20180730= 
['live/live_raw/july18/xxxx_yyyyyyyyy_zzzzzzz_20180730_MET40.txt',
     'live/live_raw/july18/xxxx_yyyyyyyyy_zzzzzzz__20180730_MET41.txt']

matching_20180731= 
['live/live_raw/july18/xxxx_yyyyyyyyy_zzzzzzz__20180731_MET42.txt',
 'live/live_raw/july18/xxxx_yyyyyyyyy_zzzzzzz__20180731_MET43.txt']

matching_20170731= 
['live/live_raw/july18/xxxx_yyyyyyyyy_zzzzzzz__20170731_MET44.txt']
```

How would you go about doing this? I can match specific strings, but not strings (or datetimes) of a certain format with this code:

```
import re
new_list = [x for x in file_list if re.search('20170731', x)]
for item in new_list:
    print(item)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Hint: When you split the string at `_` then the date is the second part from the end.

Comment: @crazyGamer, I have this: import re
new_list = [x for x in file_list if re.search(('%Y%m%d'), x)]
for item in new_list:
    print(item)